# Replace function in SSIS Derived Column

Tags: ssis

**column**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I have average value of this column,
I want to replace numbers between "0 & average value" with String as "below average"

`REPLACE(column,"[0,avg]","below")` --> but it is not working

Any ideas how to implement this ?

Comment: Why would you expect the above syntax to work - it's completely made up?

Comment: Any idea how to implement it in a better way??

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is that you will need to consume your source data twice. The first time to compute the average of all the values in `column`. Since you don't specify anything, the possibilities of how to get there are endless.

If the source system is a rdbms, then you could simply derive the message in the source query

```
SELECT
    D.[column]
,   AVG(D.[column]) OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS column_avg
,   CASE WHEN AVG(D.[column]) OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) >= D.[column] THEN CAST(D.[column] AS varchar(10))
    ELSE 'below'
    END AS ColumnAvgText
FROM
(
    VALUES(1)
    ,   (2)
    ,   (3)
    ,   (4)
    ,   (5)
    ,   (6)
    ,   (7)
    ,   (8)
    ,   (9)
    ,   (10)

)D([column]);
```

Otherwise, you're going to need to aggregate the Column for its average and then store that to a variable - I'll assume `@[User::MyAverage]`

Then in your existing data flow, you would add a new column called ColumnAvgText. The data type here must change from our original number type to a string as you can't put the word 'below' in a number field.

The syntax for that would be something like

```
(@[User::MyAverage >= column) ? ((DT_WSTR, 20) column) : "below"
```

`(DT_WSTR, 20) column` casts the value of column to string data type so that both results of the expression are string.

Comment: Is it possible to do with one pass with a multicast? I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: @KeithL Possibly but it'd be cantankerous to maintain. A Derived Column would need to inject a new column `JoinColumn` with a value like 0. Multicast output 1 goes to Aggregate transform where we do the average and retains the JoinColumn. Then a Union All joins that stream back to Multicast output 2 based on our JoinColumn. Then a Derived column as outlined in my answer

Comment: Not Union All, Merge Join. Derpity derp on my part